# Why does this sequence not converge in the norm, but it does in the strong operator topology

Tags: functional-analysis

Here follows the question and after what I did to work it out:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\{e_1,e_2,...\}$ an orthonormal sequence in $H$ (not necessarily an ONB). Define $\varphi_n\in H^*$ by $\varphi_n(x)=\langle x,e_n\rangle$. Prove that $\varphi_n\rightarrow0$ strongly, but not in the norm.

My attempt:
By Bessel's inequality:
$\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}|\langle x,e_i\rangle|^2\leq\lVert x\rVert^2$. Now take the partial sum of this, so
$S_N=\sum_{i=1}^N|\langle x,e_i\rangle|^2$, then this is also $\leq0$.Take $\{S_N\}$, this sequence is bounded by $\lVert x \rVert$ for all $x\in H$ and is increasing, thus convergent. (monotone bounded sequences are convergent.) Now the series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty|\langle x,e_i\rangle|^2$ is convergent as the sequence of its partial sums is. This implies $|\langle x,e_i\rangle|^2$ converges to $0$, and so $\langle x,e_n \rangle$ converges to $0$, implying $\varphi_n\rightarrow0$ strongly.

Now I'm not sure how to show it doesn't converge in the norm, which means $\lVert \varphi_n-\varphi\rVert\rightarrow 0$, with $\varphi$ the limit of $\varphi_n$. Any hints on how to show this and critiques on my attempt on showing the strong convergence are very welcome!!

Comment: If a sequence $T_n$ tends strongly to $0$ and $T_n$ is norm convergent then it must converge to $0,$ i.e. $\|T_n\|\to 0.$ In your case $\varphi_n$ is a nonzero orthogonal projection. Hence $\|\varphi_n\|=1.$ Thus it is not norm convergent.

Answer (score 1):

$\|\phi_n-\phi_m\|\geq |\phi_n (e_n)-\phi_m(e_n)|=1-0=1$ whenver $n \neq m$. Thus, $(\phi_n)$ is not Cauchy, hence not convergent.

[If $T$ is any bounded operator and $\|x\|=1$ then $\|T\|\geq \|Tx\|$ by the definition of $\|T\|$. Take $T=\phi_n-\phi_m$ and $x=e_n$].

Comment: That is quite neat, so we use the fact that the limit function of $\varphi_n$ isn't equal to $\varphi_n$ and therefore when we take $x=e_n$, the limit function is $0$, due to the the $e_i$ being orthogonal and $\varphi_n$ is $1$, due to the $e_i$ being orthonormal? Do we know the limit function of $\varphi_n$  is a function that needs to be of the form $\varphi_m$? Also, was my attempt at the first part correct?

Comment: Your attempt at the first part is correct and very clear. You only need the fact that convergence of  a series $\sum a_n$ implies that $a_n \to 0$.  @JackpotWizard180

Comment: Yes you are right, I didn't show that part. Also, like stated in my previous comment, how do we know that the limit function of $\varphi_n$ is a function that needs to be of the form $\varphi_m$? Thanks

Comment: Ohh, does it use not-Cauchy implies not convergent?

Comment: I am using the fact that not Cauchy implies not convergent. @JackpotWizard180